# Effects of perturbation on level set.

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, defined as $f:x\mapsto \|x\|^2_2$.

It's evident that the pre-image $f^{-1}(1)$ becomes $(n-1)$-sphere $S^{n-1}$.

Consider a **smooth** $\epsilon$-perturbation $g$ of $f$ in the uniform sense:

$$\|f-g\|_{\operatorname{sup}}<\epsilon$$

I want to prove that **$g^{-1}(1)$ **can not be embedded** in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$** if $\epsilon$ is a sufficiently small value.

If $g^{-1}(1)$ is a manifold, it is clear because a compact $(n-1)$-manifold can not be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$.

However, I am not sure that $g^{-1}(1)$ is a manifold because $1$ is not necessarily the regular value of $g$.

But it should be something very similar to $S^{n-1}$ because it divides the entire Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ into (at least) two components, $g^{-1}([0,1))\supset B_{1-\epsilon}(0) $ and $g^{-1}((1,\infty))\supset \mathbb{R}^n - B_{1+\epsilon}(0) $.

Any assistance you can offer would be greatly appreciated.